# Is there a way I can programatically control the Google Chrome policies that are found in G Suite Admin Console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-chrome-os, google-admin-settings-api

I'm looking for an API or a method that will allow me to programmatically control the Chrome polices that are found under the Chrome Device Management in G Suite Admin Console.

I'm looking for a way that will allow me to control the Chrome policies through a script or something as I have some requirements for such automation for Chrome policies in the Admin Console, such as black-listing a URL or white-listing an addon and so on...

I hope there will be a way for this or an acceptable workaround
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would think the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) would be the place to look through to control chrome device policies.

Also have a look at [Guide: Manage Chrome Devices](http://%20https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-chrome-devices) for some direction on managing chrome devices via the Directory API: